# Does android application runs in Background?

Tags: android

I'm developing android application in which I have to notify when application get into background.

Can you guys let me know whether android app runs in background? Also **lifecycle** of android app in application level.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on definitions, but yes essentially, an android app is sent to the background and certain operations can wake / communicate that app.

An article about [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that Android OS can destroy your application at any time if it's on background. Memory is finite and the more application you have running the higher the chance is of your application being destroyed.